# How can I detect when my standalone Java application was shut down?

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

I have a standalone Java application that acts as a consumer that connects to an ActiveMQ queue. In my application's `main()` method, I create an instance of the consumer as a thread and start it.

Seeing that I'm using JMS for this, I want to add a shutdown hook to my application so that when my application stops working (either terminated or killed), my application would run some method wherein all my resources will be closed.

I already tried `Runtime.addShutdownHook()` but it doesn't seem to be invoked whenever I shut down my application.

I would like it to act as if the `contextDestroyed()` method of a `ServletContextListener` was invoked.

Comment: How exactly are you shutting down your application? There is no way to add a hook that is guaranteed to run with every shutdown method; the OS can simply terminate the process of your application without allowing any code to run.

Comment: Well, for now since I'm only developing, I use Eclipse to run and terminate my app. Once I finally package it in a JAR, I would most probably run it using a linux shell and terminate it using Ctrl+C.

Comment: ```Runtime.addShutdownHook()``` will be invoked only in case of a graceful shutdown, i.e. when you do a CTRL+C or Kill, but if you do a hard shutdown, i.e. in the case of Kill -9, this shutdownHook will not be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Runtime.addShutdownHook()` is the correct API to use, but unfortunately the "Stop" button in Eclipse terminates the process without allowing any hooks to run. See [Shutdown hook doesn't work in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836551/shutdownhook-in-eclipse) for more information.

Comment: So are you saying that if I package my app as a just and run it independently from any IDE, the hook would work?